# Command App for Changing Window Title

Tags: command-line

Inside a command prompt window (cmd.exe) changing the title is very simple:

**Title** *Any Chosen Name*

Here are a couple of applets that will change the title name for any visible window:

https://www.murgee.com/window-title-changer/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/windowtitle/

I need an applet with command support.  I don't want to open a new window to change
the title of another window.

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to permanently change a window title.  The title change
should be temporary, only when a window is visible.

It seems like there should be a command line app that changes a window title.  I've
googled variations on words like "command support change window title."  Can't
find anything.

(I just clicked some similar links here at Super User.  Folks are listing other apps, but they
don't offer command support.)

Comment: Answered in [Changing title of an application when launching from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033389/3536342)

Comment: [Peter Hinchley : Changing Window Titles using PowerShell](https://hinchley.net/articles/changing-window-titles-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks David.

I like stand alone executables.  I frequently create dialog boxes that run as exe files, so they
can be plugged into anything.

I keep a few command line apps (like NirCmd) in the Windows directory.  Is this command line
ok for SetText?

C:\WINDOWS\SetText.exe "Untitled - Notepad" "A Renamed Notepad"